# OpenLayer3 overlays displayed only on one map

Tags: openlayers-3

Im working with OpenLayer3 nad overlays. I created a few of them but when I zoomed out  ( a few world maps are displayed), the overlays are displayed only on one one world map. But on the others world maps, they are not displayed.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a limitation in OpenLayers 3 - vector layers do not support wrapping the world. A workaround would be to configure your tile layers to not wrap the world, using the `wrapX: false` config option.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but OL3 API Documentation is not saying anything about wrapX:). How to use it? To which class it belongs to?

Comment: also read about doing it via wrapX, there is nothing about it mentioned in the documentation. currently the debug-ol ist also not running without errors. quite hard. comment if you found a proper solution please.

Comment: See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/apidoc/ol.source.XYZ.html?unstable=true for XYZ sources, http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/apidoc/ol.source.BingMaps.html?unstable=true for Bing, and http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html?unstable=true for OSM. Whenever you have trouble finding something in the API docs, try unchecking the "Stable" checkbox to reveal experimental features.

Answer (score 1):

**wrapX**, is now part of the current release of OpenLayers (v 3.2.0).
So if you want your layer to prevent multiple worlds. Just put it on your layer-source. See the example below:

```
                tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM({
                        wrapX: false
                    })
                });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .... but I cannot find it in documentation :)http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html

Comment: yes, sry no improvements on documentation. but did it work for you sceneario also you can always take a look into the code of ol-debug.js, searching for the implementation of wrapX.

Comment: Here is the correct link to the documentation: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.0/apidoc/ol.source.OSM.html?unstable=true.